# Does XNA apps run on Windows RT?

Tags: xna-4.0

How can I deploy XNA apps to run on Windows RT running on ARM tablets?

Answer (score 0):

the [XnaWinRT project on CodePlex](http://xnawinrt.codeplex.com/) seems to allow you to do. So the answer must be **yes, sort of**.

it says:

> .... However XNA Game Studio is Officially not supported by Microsoft.
>   This has led to developers migrating to DirectX which is a unmanaged
>   and a extensively large development framework for Games....,
>   Officially there is no support for XNA Game Studio in Windows
>   8(WinRT). So this is a light weight XNA Framework made using the .NET
>   4.5 and Metro Style APIs and is the most basic and crude form of XNA for Windows 8. More development is in Progress. Help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

No it is not and will not be supported.

However there are great alternatives like monogame which tries to map to the XNA api and you can also try Unity which while not being XNA does use c# and is very easy and flexible.

Try Unity or monogame, however just remember that unity is not XNA and while monogame looks like XNA (from an API level) it is up to 20 times slower.

Comment: So you say currently there is no way to write cross MS platform, managed framework to do the DirectX?